# My physician gave my meds away to another patient. Has he broken any laws?

Tags: united-states, medical

I receive my essential medication through a patient assistance program for the needy.  They are not a controlled substance.

The patient assistance program does not send medications directly to needy patients.  As such, my meds are sent directly to my physician for my sole use.

My physician gave away my medication to another patient.

Now I don't have access to my medication.

The cost of my medication is about $900.  I don't have $900.

I have tried to work with my physician and his staff to replace it, but have been unsuccessful for over a month.  I keep getting excuses even though I have been assertive by calling every week begging for my medication.

The patient assistance program will not send another batch of my meds, because they have signed proof that my meds were delivered to my physician.

Has my physician broken any laws?

Comment: davidgo's answer suggests that you should be more concerned about civil remedies than criminal, and that's probably true.  Is there a patient advocacy group anywhere that can help you with this?  Perhaps try legal aid -- if you can't pay $900 for your meds, you presumably can't pay $900 for a lawyer, in which case, they may be willing to help you.

Comment: It is unlikely that this can be answered without further information, especially about the program. Does the doctor have some contract with a pharma company? Do you have evidence of willful wrongdoing as opposed to bureaucratic mistake? Do you have some kind of agreement with the doctor pertaining to the meds?

Answer (score 7):

IANAL, and I don't live in America, but some of this depends on their intent.  If they gave the drugs away by mistake, they probably have not broken any laws.  If they were given away deliberately (and you would need to prove this – which might be hard) then yes, he has broken laws.

Either way, I expect you have a right to compensation (i.e. $900) from the physician to "make you whole again."  If required necessary you could file for that in your local small claims court: The physician will either come to the party pretty quickly and sort it out, or the court will award you the money you need to buy the replacement meds.  (But you will need to evidence the replacement cost, for a start....)